# WIX InstallUtil/InstallUtilLib and Configuration File Deployment why is InstallUtil bad?

Tags: configuration, wix, installutil

I often find the quote "InstallUtil.exe" is an ugly pattern or "Don't use InstallUtil.exe" and that I should use native WIX or Installation package patterns and I still don't understood why.

I stepped away from using InstallUtil to install a .NET service as I finally learnt that writing registry keys for such an action should be an un-install-able action - and I've come to terms with this as correct.

As I've been working through my WIX installer for a relatively complex product, I have found myself in need of creating or updating SQL Server databases, creating or updating IIS Applications and finally updating or creating configuration files.

Each of my components (features) are optional, but they all share the same configuration file. As my product uses unity, its important to note that this library contains strong support for reading/updating/removing components from the Unity Configuration block, therefore it seems fairly smart to me that I should take advantages of these blocks via Installation Components (i.e. InstallUtil) to create or update my configuration file at installation time.

Just to be clear here, my installer does not natively contain a configuration file for my application: at installation time, the installer has no idea as to the shape of it as its based on the features selected. Surely I should be embedding this knowledge into each of the modules that are to be deployed and not in the remit of the installer which is now a completely independent project? Wouldn't this break O-O principals even if we are talking about installation?

I'd really appreciate some guidance as to whether this is good practise or not? Am I reading 'InstallUtil' is bad for installing *services*, or is it that using 'InstallUtil' is **bad full-stop**? If so, what are my options for smart updating of configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for avoiding InstallUtil is that it runs outside of the installation transaction, so Windows Installer cannot keep track of what it's done.

I have used InstallUtil on a few occasions, when I just couldn't get Wix to do what I needed and didn't have time to write a custom action.  In this case I called the InstallUtilLib version as I feel this is a cleaner approach.

I used the this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josealmeida/archive/2004/11/08/253831.aspx) as a guide as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer there David, I have the tendency to think that my assemblies should be aware of how to deploy themselves to a certain extent. For example, the creation of configuration files on the fly. I'm not sure whether this would be considered evil or not, but it allows the application in question to control the config file and keep closely coupled information. Non installer minded developers would then not bother updating the installation package.

Comment: The example in the blog did not work for me on .NET 4.0 until I removed the '/BinDir="[TARGETDIR]\" /Package="[ProductName]"' part. It seems that part is no longer needed.

Comment: @JorritSchippers Hello. I'm trying to make it work. What is "$SampleComponent" variable? Can you maybe share working wix xml? I'm really lost.